Zabbix Proxy 6.4 Cannot send heartbeat message to 'server'
I have configured a Zabbix Proxy version 6.4 and I am trying to add it to my zabbix server, but I am getting 'last seen age' as never.
The installation process was the following one:
wget [1]https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_6.4-1+ubuntu22.04_all.deb

dpkg -i zabbix-release_6.4-1+ubuntu22.04_all.deb

apt update

apt upgrade

apt install zabbix-sql-scripts

apt install zabbix-proxy-mysql

apt-get install mysql-server

mysql -uroot -p

 mysql> create database zabbix character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_bin; 
mysql> create user zabbix@localhost identified by ‘updatev6’; 
mysql> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost;

mysql> Flush privileges;

 mysql> set global log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1; mysql> quit;

cat /usr/share/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/proxy.sql | mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -uzabbix -p zabbix

Disable log_bin_trust_function_creators

mysql -uroot -p

mysql> set global log_bin_trust_function_creators = 0;

mysql> quit;

Configuramos /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.conf

DBPassword=updatev6

ProxyConfigFrequency=100

Server=dnsaddressofthezabbixserver.com

Hostname=monitoringproxy

ServerPort=10051

ListenPort=10056

StartPollers=100

StartVMwareCollectors=5

VMwareCacheSize=512M

TLSConnect=psk

TLSAccept=psk

TLSPSKIdentity=PROXY-”NOMBRE CLIENTE”-01

TLSPSKFile=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk

openssl rand -hex 32 | nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk (copiar WPA)

chown zabbix:zabbix /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk

chmod 644 /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk

sudo systemctl restart zabbix-proxy

sudo systemctl enable zabbix-proxy

Apt install zabbix-agent

sudo systemctl restart zabbix-agent

sudo systemctl enable zabbix-agent

Systemctl status zabbix-agent


Once I finished the process and also added it to the zabbix server, I get the following error on the logs:

Note: the hostname of the proxy registered on the zabbix server, zabbix proxy and zabbix proxy.conf file are the same.
I tried following the installation process again, checking that the hostname registered on the zabbix_proxy.conf, hostname and the one registered on the zabbix server are the same.
I was expecting to stop the 'Last seen age' to be never. But I did not get that result
